# Is there a way to access and manage Etsy Ad data using Etsy API?

Tags: product, ads, etsy

I am wanting to be able to access Etsy Ad data in order to document views, clicks, and manage keywords that led to the ads, but I see no way to in the Etsy API documentation. Am I missing something? Or is there no way to do this?